# How can I make a shared printer with separator page not access a different paper tray?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, printing

From within Windows 2003 we have deployed printers using group policy.  These printers have worked for several years this way and recently in a computer lab we decided to add a separator page to flag which users were printing large jobs.  Now when a user prints, the job prints the separator page, then pauses until the user physically walks over to the print device and presses the go button.  The error message that is displayed is that the tray is out of paper.  There is only one tray of paper on this HP Laserjet 4100.  We are using the HP Universal Print Driver PCL 5 and the sysprint.sep page (although it has the same behavior with the pcl.sep page)

How can you set this up so it prints without the need for pressing the button to continue?

Comment: You need to give us something to work with here -- "It's Broken!" is the worst possible problem description. Please read [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608) and edit your question into something answerable, and we will consider re-opening it.

Comment: @voretaq7 Please review and re-open.  thanks!

Comment: Big improvement :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the message the printer is giving you ("out of paper") I'm going to take a guess and say that your separator page is specifying a paper type or size that your printer doesn't have (e.g. you're printing on US/Letter but the separator page specifies A4).

Depending on how the separator page is handled (prepended/appended to the job, or as a separate job on its own) this could cause the printer to pause waiting for the user to OK a paper change before it can proceed.

Double-check your separator page definition to be sure it matches the size (and type) of paper the printer/driver thinks it has loaded.